# apt update игнорирует локальные репозитории

Tags: linux, debian

В общем сразу к делу.

**Debian 10.0**

Загрузка локального репозитория произведена через **apt-mirror** на подключенный по USB жесткий диск.

Файл конфига apt-mirror

```
    ############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /media/alex/linux/zerkalo
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

clean http://deb.debian.org/debian
```

где /media/alex/linux/zerkalo точка сохранения
Папки zerkalo и подпапки mirror,skel,var были созданы заранее

Далее была введена команда 
*sudo apt-mirror*
После чего началась долгая загрузка, которая прошла успешно.

Далее локальные репозитории были добавлены /etc/apt/sources.list

Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
deb file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free

deb file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free

deb file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
```

Далее вводится команда *sudo apt update*
Результат следующий

```
Пол:1 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39,1 kB]
Пол:1 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39,1 kB]
Пол:2 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49,3 kB]
Пол:2 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49,3 kB]
Пол:3 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease [46,7 kB]
Пол:3 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease [46,7 kB]
Пол:4 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [118 kB]
Пол:4 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [118 kB]
Пол:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [29,8 kB]
Игн:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources
Пол:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [62,9 kB]
Игн:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Пол:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en [35,9 kB]
Игн:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en
Пол:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [29,8 kB]
Пол:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [62,9 kB]
Пол:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en [35,9 kB]
Игн:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources
Игн:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en
Пол:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [37,6 kB]
Игн:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Игн:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources
Пол:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en [319 kB]
Игн:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en
Пол:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [76,2 kB]
Игн:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
Пол:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [37,6 kB]
Пол:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en [319 kB]
Игн:5 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources
Ошб:7 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en
  Файл не найден - /media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: Нет такого файла или каталога)
Пол:6 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [76,2 kB]
Пол:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources [1 204 B]
Игн:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources
Пол:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [884 B]
Игн:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Пол:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en [600 B]
Игн:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en
Пол:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources [1 204 B]
Игн:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources
Пол:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [884 B]
Игн:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Пол:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en [600 B]
Игн:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en
Пол:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources [1 139 B]
Игн:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources
Пол:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [809 B]
Игн:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Пол:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en [967 B]
Игн:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en
Пол:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources [1 139 B]
Игн:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources
Пол:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [809 B]
Игн:9 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages
Пол:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en [967 B]
Ошб:10 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en
  Файл не найден - /media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: Нет такого файла или каталога)
Пол:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources [2 523 B]
Игн:8 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources
Пол:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources [1 016 B]
Игн:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources
Пол:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources [51,5 kB]
Игн:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources
Пол:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources [1 768 B]
Игн:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources
Пол:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages [80,1 kB]
Игн:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
Пол:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en [63,1 kB]
Игн:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en
Пол:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages [4 620 B]
Игн:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
Пол:17 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Translation-en [2 844 B]
Игн:17 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Translation-en
Пол:18 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages [1 816 B]
Игн:18 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
Пол:19 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Translation-en [872 B]
Игн:19 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Translation-en
Пол:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources [1 016 B]
Игн:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources
Пол:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources [51,5 kB]
Игн:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources
Пол:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources [1 768 B]
Игн:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources
Пол:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages [80,1 kB]
Пол:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en [63,1 kB]
Игн:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
Игн:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en
Пол:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages [4 620 B]
Игн:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
Пол:17 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Translation-en [2 844 B]
Игн:17 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Translation-en
Пол:18 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages [1 816 B]
Игн:18 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
Пол:19 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Translation-en [872 B]
Игн:19 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Translation-en
Пол:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources [2 072 B]
Игн:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources
Пол:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources [254 kB]
Игн:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources
Пол:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources [4 675 B]
Игн:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources
Пол:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages [494 kB]
Игн:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
Пол:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en [364 kB]
Игн:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en
Пол:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages [17,6 kB]
Игн:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
Пол:17 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Translation-en [10,1 kB]
Игн:17 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Translation-en
Пол:18 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages [5 609 B]
Игн:18 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
Пол:19 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Translation-en [2 979 B]
Игн:19 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Translation-en
Пол:11 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/non-free Sources [2 072 B]
Пол:12 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Sources [254 kB]
Пол:13 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib Sources [4 675 B]
Пол:14 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages [494 kB]
Пол:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en [364 kB]
Ошб:15 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main Translation-en
  Файл не найден - /media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: Нет такого файла или каталога)
Пол:16 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib amd64 Packages [17,6 kB]
Пол:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources [43,1 kB]
Игн:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources
Пол:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources [86,2 kB]
Игн:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources
Пол:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources [7 827 kB]
Игн:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources
Пол:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7 897 kB]
Игн:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Пол:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru [516 kB]
Игн:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru
Пол:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en [5 967 kB]
Игн:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en
Пол:26 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 807 kB]
Игн:26 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Пол:27 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3 770 kB]
Игн:27 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Пол:28 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7 596 kB]
Игн:28 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:29 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages [51,0 kB]
Игн:29 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Пол:30 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Translation-en [44,7 kB]
Игн:30 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Translation-en
Пол:31 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,5 kB]
Игн:31 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Пол:32 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 48x48 Icons [56,4 kB]
Игн:32 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Пол:33 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons [110 kB]
Игн:33 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:34 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages [88,0 kB]
Игн:34 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages
Пол:35 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Translation-en [88,3 kB]
Игн:35 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Translation-en
Пол:36 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9 096 B]
Игн:36 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Пол:37 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3 491 B]
Игн:37 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Пол:38 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons [38,3 kB]
Игн:38 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources [43,1 kB]
Игн:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources
Пол:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources [86,2 kB]
Игн:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources
Пол:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources [7 827 kB]
Игн:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources
Пол:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7 897 kB]
Игн:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Пол:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru [516 kB]
Игн:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru
Пол:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en [5 967 kB]
Игн:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en
Пол:26 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 807 kB]
Игн:26 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Пол:27 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3 770 kB]
Игн:27 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Пол:28 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7 596 kB]
Игн:28 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:29 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages [51,0 kB]
Игн:29 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
Пол:30 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Translation-en [44,7 kB]
Игн:30 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Translation-en
Пол:31 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,5 kB]
Игн:31 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Пол:32 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 48x48 Icons [56,4 kB]
Игн:32 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Пол:33 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons [110 kB]
Игн:33 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:34 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages [88,0 kB]
Игн:34 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages
Пол:35 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Translation-en [88,3 kB]
Игн:35 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Translation-en
Пол:36 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9 096 B]
Игн:36 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Пол:37 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3 491 B]
Игн:37 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Пол:38 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons [38,3 kB]
Игн:38 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources [50,5 kB]
Игн:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources
Пол:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources [103 kB]
Игн:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources
Пол:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources [10,3 MB]
Игн:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources
Пол:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [10,6 MB]
Игн:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Пол:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru [3 168 kB]
Игн:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru
Пол:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en [29,3 MB]
Игн:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en
Пол:26 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5 883 kB]
Игн:26 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Игн:38 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Пол:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources [50,5 kB]
Игн:20 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib Sources
Пол:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources [103 kB]
Игн:21 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free Sources
Пол:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources [10,3 MB]
Игн:22 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources
Пол:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [10,6 MB]
Пол:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru [3 168 kB]
Игн:23 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Ошб:24 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-ru
  Файл не найден - /media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/i18n/Translation-ru (2: Нет такого файла или каталога)
Пол:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en [29,3 MB]
Игн:25 file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово   
N: Загрузка выполняется от лица суперпользователя без ограничений песочницы, так как файл «/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease» недоступен для пользователя «_apt». - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Отказано в доступе)
E: Не удалось получить file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Файл не найден - /media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: Нет такого файла или каталога)
E: Не удалось получить file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Файл не найден - /media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: Нет такого файла или каталога)
E: Некоторые индексные файлы скачать не удалось. Они были проигнорированы, или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

Вопрос, что не так? Почему я не могу выполнить apt update? 
Некоторые "Пол" и "Игн" строки были вырезаны, дабы уместить всё основное.
Все файлы существуют. Проблемы с правами? Кому должен пренадлежать каталог? В данный момент он принадлежит моему пользователю.

Comment: Формат URL начинается с `file://`, догадайтесь, как будет выглядеть путь к корневому каталогу.

Comment: @0andriy  это локальный репозиторий, а локальный URL не может начинаться с //. Догадываетесь с чего он начнется? Правильно либо с / либо с ///.

Comment: Traditional vs. minimal как нас учит RFC. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Репозиторий был автоматически смонтирован debian в /media/alex/linux

Нужно размонтировать с помощью umount 
И замонтировать обратно в другой каталок с помощью mount, например /mnt/linux
где linux имя раздела на жестком диске

Comment: То есть в момент ошибки файлов по `file:/media/alex/linux/zerkalo/mirror/security.debian.org/debian-security` попросту не было?

Comment: Было, все файлы были по указанному пути, но диск был смонтирован автоматчески при подключении по usb в /media/alex, что крайне не нравилось apt, после пермонтирования в ручную в /mnt/mydisk и изменении пути на новый ошибка ушла.